# Flutter Dart parse advanced expressions

Tags: flutter, dart, parsing, math, expression

I have string with a lot of expressions, and must return true or false. I tried do it using this library: https://pub.dev/packages/expression_language/example but have some problems with strings.

This is sample of code from library:

```dart
import 'package:expression_language/expression_language.dart';

void main() {
var input = '\"Hello 1 + 1 equals: \" +  (1 + 1)'
  var expressionGrammarDefinition = ExpressionGrammarParser({});
  var parser = expressionGrammarDefinition.build();
  var result = parser.parse(input);
  var expression = result.value as Expression;
  var value = expression.evaluate();
  print(value);
}
```

output is: `Hello 1 + 1 equals: 2`

But my expressions are more complicated, for example:

```dart
input = '(!\"Dog\" == \"Cat\")';
input = '(1+1) || (\"Dog\" == \"Dog\")';
input = '(1+1) + (\"2\" * 2)';
```

I can parse this using `expression_language` library? Maybe exist better solution?

Answer (score 1):

`expression_language` is built with `petitparser`, which is a very flexible general purpose parser.  If you learn petitparser, you'll be able to build anything!  (You may never write another regex in Dart as well.)

Comment: Thank You, now I read some about PetitParser, but probably this library cannot help me solve my problem. I still do not know, how to solve simple boolean logic expression with strings. For example it is true: 'varA == "X" && !varB' if varA="X" and varB=false? If we use this variable in expression: '"X"=="X" && !false' => "true && true' => 'true'

Comment: You can certainly build your domain-specific language with petitparser.  It will take some learning, but once you have petitparser knowledge, lexing and parsing and evaluating problems will be relatively straightforward.